# Booleans always evaluated as true, despite being false

Tags: java

I have been programming a basic game engine which creates a 2D array of booleans for the map. I am trying to generate walls to block the player from entering non-existent rooms.

Ideally, when an adjacent true boolean is detected in the "map" 2d array, the walls connecting the 2 true rooms should be removed in the respective Room (object consisting of a 2d array of integers called "structure" in the array "floor".

I have added a System.out.println() line in order to check the booleans in case I had been assigning them all true values mistakenly, bu this is not the case. They vary between true and false as they should, but they are all nonetheless evaluated as true, leading to no walls existing at all.

```
public static Room[][] genWalls(Room[][] floor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < floor.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < floor[0].length; j++) {
            if (Game.map[i][j]) {
                if (i - 1 > 0) {
                    System.out.println(Game.map[i][j - 1]);
                    if (Game.map[i][j - 1]) {
                        floor[i][j].structure[5][1] = 0;
                        floor[i][j].structure[6][1] = 0;
                        floor[i][j].structure[7][1] = 0;
                    }
                }
```

This section of the method genWalls is expected to remove the leftmost wall in the int[][] "structure" of the respective floor, and the aforementioned printing failsafe is included.

As mentioned earlier some of the booleans are true and some are false, but they all pass through the if operator.

Comment: How have you determined that the `if (Game.map[i][j]) { ... }` block is executing when `Game.map[i][j]` is false? As a simple test, insert `System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j + ", map[i][j] = " + Game.map[i][j]);` before the `if` statement and `System.out.println("Evaluated as true");` just inside the `if` block.

Comment: My best advice would be to step through this with your debugger, so you can see what's _really_ happening.  Also make sure you didn't insert an extra `;` after the `if` condition.

Comment: Won't your code crash when `j` is zero and you call `Game.map[i][j - 1]`?

Comment: Show your data, class and data loading

Comment: just move the `println` inside the `if` block (eventually adding coordinates)

Comment: `if (i - 1 > 0)`  Really? `if ( i  > 1 )` avoids the math step (a good optimizer should do this for you anyway).